# Передача переменных по const& вместо передачи по значению. Плюсы и минусы

Tags: c++, переменные, ссылки

Доброго времени суток. Только что коллега, читая мой код заметил, что я все переменные передаю в методы по const& ссылке вместо того что бы передавать их по значению. Я всегда считал такой подход более производительным (в некоторых случаях) и более красивым. Не помню откуда я подчерпнул этот стиль, но мой коллега категорический с ним не согласен. Вопрос собственно вот в чём, действительно ли есть другие программисты, которые используют такой подход к передаче обычных переменных, какие у этого подхода преимущества и недостатки, и стоит ли мне и дальше продолжать так делать или стоит переучиться передавать простые переменные по значению в случаях, когда я не собираюсь их изменять?

```
uint32_t Foo1 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

vs

```
uint32_t Foo2(const uint32_t& a, const uint32_t& b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Вообще, если вы не собираетесь изменять переменную (это не объект, а именно переменная), то, имхо, лучше конечно передовать значение. Это добавит читабельности, да и если нужно значение изменить (именно в ф-ции), то с этим проблем никогда не будет. Но все это чисто имхо.

Comment: применение `const &` к интегральным типом никогда не встречается в коде, написанном грамотным C++-программистом. Для других типов это было стандартом де-факто до появления C++11, после которого начались брожения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все нужно использовать с умом. Есть у Страуструпа не передавать по значению типы, которые больше 8-12 байт.

Рассмотрим пример с uint32. Сама переменная занимает 4 байта. А вот ссылка на нее будет как минимум те же 4. Если повезет и компилятор сомптимизирует, то ничего страшного и не будет. Но вот ссылка может стать и указателем, и тогда это может в 8 байт превратиться. А это уже менее оптимально.

Второе, что может быть, это то, что компилятор скорее всего хуже соптимизирует ссылку на константу (как бы это не казалось странным). Когда передается значение, компилятор более чем уверен, что оно не поменяется без его ведома. А вот ссылка на константу может поменяться (да, это удивительно). У вызывающей функции это ведь не обязательно константа. А переменная, которая передается в функцию, может использоваться в других местах, в других тредах... [на почитать](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#aliasing-and-const)

Также не стоит забывать, что сейчас уже давно есть "модная штука" - move семантика. А она иногда очень сильно помогает при "копировании тяжелых объектов".

Comment: Ну int32 скорее всего всё равно при передаче на x64 расширяется до 64 бит, а с потоками вроде вообще ничего не гарантируется. В остальном вроде согласен.

Comment: С потоками в новых стандартах (с++11 и старше) много чего гарантируется.

Comment: @Qwertiy, куда оно расширяется? Для кого там 32 в имени типа?

Comment: видимо имеется ввиду, что в amd64 соглашении первые 5 параметров передаются через регистры, которые могут использоваться как 64битные.

Comment: Ну, все операции всё равно будут над 32-х битными частями выполняться. У @Vtt в ответе есть листинг с 64-х бит, который это прекрасно иллюстрирует.

Comment: @ixSci, у int8 тоже 8 в имени типа, но при передаче в функцию передаётся не 8, а 32 (на x32). Есть подозрение, что на x64 будет 64. Это не изменение типа, а выравнивание или что-то такое.

Comment: не обязательно https://godbolt.org/g/R1kGVv

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде все оптимизации должны приводить к коду, неотличимому в рамках одного потока? А для разных надо уже хотя бы volatile расставлять? Или нет?

Comment: Я думаю, об этом могут судить только ребята с комитета по стандартизации и разработчики компиляторов.

Answer (score 4):

1. Передавая крупные объекты по ссылке, ты экономишь на копировании.
2. Передавая int64 (или меньше) по ссылке, ты на копировании ничего не экономишь, поскольку указатель занимает тот же объём.
3. Каждая операция со ссылкой на число требует разыменования указателя - это минус к производительности.
4. Теоретически значение по ссылке может поменяться. В части случаев это может привести к отключению кучи оптимизаций. А ещё это может неожиданно оказаться багом - я так один раз очень долго метод Гаусса дебажил, когда в качестве коэффициента передал по ссылке элемент матрицы, которую меняю.

## Вот пример:

```
void fill_val(char *a, unsigned n, char ch) {
  for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
    a[q] = ch + 1;
}

void fill_ref(char *a, unsigned n, const char &ch) {
  for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
    a[q] = ch + 1;
}
```

### x86-64 gcc 7.2: https://godbolt.org/g/iM9uXj

Вот первая функция - загрузили значение в регистр, увеличили на 1, прошли по массиву через указатель и записали в него значение.

```
fill_val(char*, unsigned int, char):
  test esi, esi
  je .L1
  lea eax, [rsi-1]
  add edx, 1
  lea rax, [rdi+1+rax]
.L3:
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi], dl
  add rdi, 1
  cmp rdi, rax
  jne .L3
.L1:
  rep ret
```

А вот вторая - на каждой итерации цикла загружаем значение из ссылки в регистр, увеличиваем его на 1 и только потом записываем в массив:

```
fill_ref(char*, unsigned int, char const&):
  test esi, esi
  je .L9
  lea eax, [rsi-1]
  lea rcx, [rdi+1+rax]
.L11:
  movzx eax, BYTE PTR [rdx]
  add rdi, 1
  add eax, 1
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi-1], al
  cmp rdi, rcx
  jne .L11
.L9:
  rep ret
```

Почему так? Да потому что возможен следующий код:

```
char a[256] = {0};
fill_ref(a, a[4]); // 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 ... 2
```

компилятор основывается на совпадении типов и отказывается от оптимизаций, которые потенциально могут привести к неверному результату.

### x86-64 clang 5.0.0: https://godbolt.org/g/JDUMnx

Первая функция - начали как gcc, потом вызвали memset - у него уже куча оптимизаций внутри и он весьма шустрый:

```
fill_val(char*, unsigned int, char): # @fill_val(char*, unsigned int, char)
  mov eax, esi
  test eax, eax
  je .LBB0_2
  push rax
  inc dl
  dec eax
  inc rax
  movzx esi, dl
  mov rdx, rax
  call memset
  add rsp, 8
.LBB0_2:
  ret
```

А вот вторая - компилятор явно старался и что-то наоптимизировал - судя по всему тут раскрутка цикла и, возможно, векторизация. Вообще-то я не очень понимаю этот код (часть команд вообще не знаю), да и вообще разбираться с ним долго:

```
fill_ref(char*, unsigned int, char const&): # @fill_ref(char*, unsigned int, char const&)
  test esi, esi
  je .LBB1_14
  mov r8d, esi
  cmp esi, 31
  jbe .LBB1_2
  lea rax, [rdx + 1]
  cmp rax, rdi
  jbe .LBB1_11
  lea rax, [rdi + r8]
  cmp rax, rdx
  jbe .LBB1_11
.LBB1_2:
  xor r9d, r9d
.LBB1_3:
  mov eax, r8d
  sub eax, r9d
  lea rsi, [r8 - 1]
  sub rsi, r9
  and rax, 3
  je .LBB1_6
  neg rax
.LBB1_5: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movzx ecx, byte ptr [rdx]
  inc cl
  mov byte ptr [rdi + r9], cl
  inc r9
  inc rax
  jne .LBB1_5
.LBB1_6:
  cmp rsi, 3
  jb .LBB1_14
  sub r8, r9
  lea rcx, [rdi + r9 + 3]
.LBB1_8: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movzx eax, byte ptr [rdx]
  inc al
  mov byte ptr [rcx - 3], al
  movzx eax, byte ptr [rdx]
  inc al
  mov byte ptr [rcx - 2], al
  movzx eax, byte ptr [rdx]
  inc al
  mov byte ptr [rcx - 1], al
  movzx eax, byte ptr [rdx]
  inc al
  mov byte ptr [rcx], al
  add rcx, 4
  add r8, -4
  jne .LBB1_8
  jmp .LBB1_14
.LBB1_11:
  and esi, 31
  mov r9, r8
  sub r9, rsi
  movzx eax, byte ptr [rdx]
  movd xmm0, eax
  punpcklbw xmm0, xmm0 # xmm0 = xmm0[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7]
  pshuflw xmm0, xmm0, 0 # xmm0 = xmm0[0,0,0,0,4,5,6,7]
  pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 80 # xmm0 = xmm0[0,0,1,1]
  pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm1
  psubb xmm0, xmm1
  lea rax, [rdi + 16]
  mov rcx, r9
.LBB1_12: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax - 16], xmm0
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax], xmm0
  add rax, 32
  add rcx, -32
  jne .LBB1_12
  test esi, esi
  jne .LBB1_3
.LBB1_14:
  ret
```

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: Ответ ещё раз обновлён.

Comment: есть подозрение, что итоговая портянка clang'а — это как раз и есть встроенный `memset`.... на `-O3` gcc кстати тоже должен был бы `memset` отыскать... ЗЫ: ссылки похоже не те...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, похоже, я godbolt'ом пользоваться не умею... Ссылки те, просто надо в средний столбец смотреть. Эта портянка могла бы быть мемсетом, если бы он внутри указатель не разыменовывал, но каким-то видоизменённым мемсетом (с его разворачиванием и векторизацией) это вполне может быть. Хотя какая векторизация, если значение может измениться?

Comment: @Qwertiy, эта хитрая сволочь проверяет (перед `.LBB1_2`), что если `ch` не указывает в массив, то векторизирует и устанавливая по 32 байта за итерацию (цикл .LBB1_12), а остаток добивает обычным способом... а если `ch` попадает, то идёт на пролом как положено...

Answer (score 4):

А вы проведите [эксперимент](https://godbolt.org/g/jtfgwP):

```
int
by_val(int const x, int const y)
{ return x + y; }

int
by_ref(int const & x, int const & y)
{ return x + y; }

int
by_ptr(int const * const p_x, int const * const p_y)
{ return *p_x + *p_y; }

int sum_by_val(int const x, int const y)
{    return by_val(x, y); }

int sum_by_ref(int const x, int const y)
{    return by_ref(x, y); }
```

Результат:

```
by_val(int, int):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
by_ref(int const&, int const&):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  ret
by_ptr(int const*, int const*):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  ret
sum_by_val(int, int):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
sum_by_ref(int, int):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
```

Как видно, в случае встраивания функции никакой разницы нет, а без встраивания передача по ссылке будет менее эффективна, так как компиляторы не заменяют передачу по константной ссылке передачей по значению (хотя могли бы).

Comment: Спасибо что разжевали.

Comment: "не заменяют передачу по константной ссылке передачей по значению (хотя могли бы)." - нет, они почти никогда не могут этого сделать - нужно для начала доказать, что ссылаются на разные объекты и объекты не могут поменяться без ведома компилятора.

Comment: _«так как компиляторы не заменяют передачу по константной ссылке передачей по значению (хотя могли бы).»_ — полагаю, что не могли бы. У них нет на это прав.

Comment: @KoVadim Объекты требуется различать далеко не всегда (другой вопрос, что выяснить это, глядя только на объявление функции не представляется возможным). А вот что объекты не могут поменяться без ведома компилятора можно не доказывать. Единственный вариант их изменения - из другого потока - является неопределенным поведением. Более того, отсутствие замены передачи по ссылке передачей по значению никак не поможет в случае состояния гонки.

Comment: @VTT, я могу снять константность с объекта, переданного в функцию и изменить его. Я даже не получу UB, если объект не был рождён константой. Если же компилятор заменит это на временный объект, то он изменит поведение программы — не имеет права. И касательно Вашего последнего комментария: это не единственный вариант изменения. Представьте, что внутри функции вызывается другая функция, которая меняет глобальный объект. Так уж случилось, что ссылка именно на этот объект передана в функцию выше. Вот и получаете изменение.

Comment: @ixSci Это хорошо, но что будет мешать компилятору в случае, когда константность с объекта не снимается, никакие другие функции внутри не вызываются, к глобальным объектам обращений нет, как в приведенном мной примере?

Comment: @VTT, думаю, что ничего. Т.е. если он может доказать, что проблем быть не может (за исключением UB), то он может так сделать. Т.е. в частном случае это возможно, да. Но маловероятно.

Answer (score 3):

Основной негативный эффект черезмерного использования ссылок — это лишний доступ к памяти. Передача по ссылке в реальности реализуется передачей указателя. Для примера можно проассемблировать эти две функции:

```
;==========================================================
; x86_64
;==========================================================
Foo1:                        |   Foo2:
    movl    %edi, %eax       |      movl    (%rdi), %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax       |      imull   (%rsi), %eax
    ret                      |      ret
                             |
;==========================================================
; x86                        
;==========================================================
Foo1:                        |  Foo2:
                             |      movl    4(%esp), %eax
                             |      movl    8(%esp), %edx
    movl    8(%esp), %eax    |      movl    (%eax), %eax
    imull   4(%esp), %eax    |      imull   (%edx), %eax
    ret                      |      ret
```

Как видно, для `x86`, где всё передаётся через стек это выливается в две лишние инструкции, лишние 8 байт в стеке и в два лишних обращения к памяти. На `x86_64` — только в два лишних обращения к памяти (радует, что хоть мимо кеша он почти наверняка не промахнётся), но проблема в том, что для вызова этой функции компилятору ещё придётся записать оба эти значения в память, а при вызове по-значению можно предать промежуточные значения сразу через регистры.

При встраивании понятно, что почти наверняка всё будет работать одинаково.

Comment: "для x86, где всё передаётся через стек" - c чего это вдруг?

Comment: @VTT cdecl — стандартная конвенция почти во всех компиляторах.... fastcall'ы обычно используются только по-требованию...